# Removing URLs from images in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

On my wordpress blog my images link to another page and I would like to remove that link. I'm pretty sure it can't be done using Wordpress' hooks and I've been trying with preg_replace, but to no success.

So Here's an example:

> This is a `<a href="">` simple link `</a>` while this is an image link `<a href=""><img src=""></a>`

So I only want the images' URL to be removed, while the text one remains.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just edit the posts to remove the links?

Comment: There are nearly 2000 posts. It wouldn't be so easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
<a href="[^"]+"> *(<img src="[^"]+" */?>) *</a>
```

and replace with '\1'.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the **the_content** filter and apply a regex with preg_replace to do that.

Here's some info and examples on using the hook: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content